# Segurança do Fonte PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um projeto em PHP e agora estarei trabalhando com mais 2 programadores nele.
Existe alguma forma de proteger o código-fonte de cópias indevidas por esse programadores?

Em especial, Existe alguma ferramenta que possa ser instalada para proibir a cópia de certos diretórios?

Grato!

Comment: Relacionado [Como proteger o código PHP de roubos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3110/91)

Comment: @rray acho que a copia é copiar pra fora da empresa... eu acho... se for isto só bloqueando a internet e os dispositivos de gravação.

Comment: Se eles vão trabalhar com esse código não existe. O que você fazer é fazer eles assinarem um termo de confidencialidade e cobrar isso judicialmente. Mas mesmo assim o código pode ser copiado.

Comment: existe alguma ferramenta que possa ser instalada para proibir a copia de certos diretórios?

Comment: @Rafael, se você tem acesso a uma informação, então você pode copiá-la, essa é uma regra fundamental da segurança. Hoje em dia com os poderosos smartphones, é fácil tirar print-screen do fonte e levar para casa, esquece. Ademais, hoje em dia, quem precisa tanto esconder código assim? o que tem de tão valioso no código? não seriam os dados mais valiosos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não queria responder a sua pergunta, mas ficou muito longo para os comentários e isso acaba servindo como resposta. Além disso, não é a primeira vez que vejo uma pergunta como essa. Portanto lá vai a resposta:

Vamos supor que você instale uma ferramenta para evitar a cópia de certos diretórios. Então eles vão lá, abrem os arquivos um por um no bloco de notas, escolhem a opção "Salvar como..." e gravam em outra pasta. FAIL!

E se não puderem gravar em outra pasta, é só copiar e colar tudo no e-mail, FAIL de novo.

Ou mesmo que você proteja bem o computador, um deles pode decidir tirar várias fotos do monitor usando o celular e depois, em algum lugar fora da sua empresa, remontarem o código.

A única forma seria se não houvesse acesso a internet e nem a Wi-Fi, nem a CD ou pen-drive e você teria que revistar eles para garantir que não tragam celulares ou máquinas fotográficas.

Além disso, mesmo que eles não copiem ou fotografem o código, eles podem levar algumas folhas de papel e canetas e copiar manualmente. Outra coisa que você teria que barrar e controlar a entrada e saída.

Entretanto, duvido que isso resulte em um ambiente de trabalho produtivo.

Ah, e nada impede eles de darem uma boa olhada no código, decorarem o que for possível, aprender como funciona e depois de botar o pé para fora da sua empresa, escreverem tudo que se lembrarem a fim de replicar o seu programa depois.

Enfim, o que você quer fazer não pode ser feito. Se você vai trabalhar com outras duas pessoas, você deve escolher profissionais de confiança e não trabalhar com qualquer um. Contratos com valor judicial servem para isso também.